# Cross site call in ajax: responseXML undefined

Tags: ajax, csrf

I'm developing a script that performs a cross site call to a python webservice, which returns a xml.
This is the full code of the html page that executes the cross site call:

```
<html>
<head>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./jquery.xdomainajax.js"></script>

  <script>        
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://api.notmywebsite.net/search/parameters",
  async: true,
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
      },
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data.responseXML);
  },
  error: function(err){
    alert("error: " + err.status);
  }
});
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="xmlOutput"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is, of course, the script isn't working:
 - When I call the webservice through the browser, the xml is successfully displayed.
 - I'm using WebScarab to check if the answer has any content, and it has. The HTTP response has the right headers and the expected XML response.
 - I debugged the python webservice to check if a call made by my request would return the expected XML, and it did.

After some research I came across the same-origin policy, for which I started using (hope i'm using it right) the following proxy: https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/blob/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js

The webservice is also called using php, through a "simplexml_load_file($url);", which returns the expected XML response.

I tried executing this same call (but using responseText instead of responseXML) to google, and it was successful.

The xml has the following format:

```
<OAI-PMH xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/OAI-PMH http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/OAI-PMH.xsd">
  <record>
    <header>
      <identifier>oai:epimarketplace.net:empid:1066</identifier>
      <datestamp>2012-06-25T14:54:01.058Z</datestamp>
      <setSpec>resource</setSpec>
      <downLink>http://api.epimarketplace.net/fetch/pid/empid:1066</downLink>
    </header>
    <metadata>
      <em>
        <metadataLink>http://api.epimarketplace.net/rawfetch/pid/empid:1066/datastream/EM</metadataLink>
        <field name="PID">empid:1066</field>
        <field name="em.dateSubmitted">2012-08-20T10:43:40Z</field>
        <field name="em.generalDescription.subject">Behaviour</field>
        <field name="em.generalDescription.type">Dataset harvested from social networks</field>
        <field name="em.title">&#60&#115&#99&#114&#105&#112&#116&#62&#88&#83&#83&#60&#47&#115&#99&#114&#105&#112&#116&#62&#10</field>
        <field name="em.uploader.name">Tiago André Posse</field>
        <field name="isCollection_b">false</field>
        <field name="nComments">0</field>
        <field name="nLikes">0</field>
      </em>
    </metadata>
  </record>
</OAI-PMH>
```

Hoping you can help me,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *responseXML* has always given me a tough time. I usually use *responseText* instead and then parse the text string into an *XML DOM object.* Anyways i'v posted certain points where you could be erring.

Comment: Does your own question not interest you anymore?? Even if you have got a solution on your own, do post it........

Answer (score 0):

In order for the browser to correctly return an XML object using responseXML, you must ensure the following:

1.Your XML document is well formed( responseXML will always return *null* if not)

2.In *Firefox*, call ***request.overrideMimeType('text/xml')*** at the start of your Ajax request (upon instantiation) to explicitly tell the browser that the returned data will have a content type of "text/xml".

3.*IE* doesn't support the client side overrideMimeType() method, so you must ensure that your server returns the proper "text/xml" content header type for the XML file that is being returned.

*NOTE:* If your XML file is named with an extension of ".xml", most servers by default send out the proper "text/xml" headers, though if it is not, you'll want to modify your server settings to do so. See "XML documents and the Content-type pitfall in IE" for more info.

***If any one of the above conditions are not met, the data returned will be as plain text, not an XML object as expected.***

**EDIT:** I looked into your JQuery Ajax call(again) and guess what?! The *responseXML* will always be undefined, as you are trying to access it even before the AJAX request has completed. My solution would be to call the function under *complete* attribute instead of *success*.